# C# Selenium WebDriver Access Denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using .NET Framework 3.5 (Visual Studio 2012) and selenium-dotnet-2.35.0 (Selenium WebDriver for .NET 3.5)

When trying to load just a basic test, I'm getting an error of:

```
Access to the path 'C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous112638264.webdriver-profile' is denied
```

I've tried starting Visual Studio in Administrator mode as well as adding to the manifest:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

With no luck

The code I'm trying (after just following simple tutorials) is:

```
FirefoxProfileManager profileMan = new FirefoxProfileManager();
FirefoxProfile fp = profileMan.GetProfile("SELENIUM"); //I've set up another FF profile
FirefoxDriver firefox = new FirefoxDriver(fp); //Triggers error
firefox.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
```

Most tutorials do not even go that indepth and only use:

```
FirefoxDriver firefox = new FirefoxDriver();
firefox.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com"); //Triggers error
```

I can't find any information online with my googling powers, any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: What's the security context you are working with? I mean who is running the process?

Comment: It's just my personal PC, I'm an administrator

Comment: No man, I mean who is running the process? Is this a windows application you are double clicking on it or a web based application pool running under IIS?

Comment: Oh sorry. Windows Forms Application, just like a Button click activates this function, this is just a simple app

Comment: Alright. What version of Windows are you using mate?

Comment: What is the status of UAC in your Windows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65793/discussion-between-rikki-rockett-and-sl133).